# How to select into multiple variables inside a trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

This is what I'd like to achieve:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_num, SUM(width) AS total_width
    FROM some_table WHERE foo = NEW.foo;
    IF total_num > 0 AND total_width > 100
    THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'this is bad';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it's not yet syntactically correct.

I've read I first need to `DECLARE` the variables (in this case `total_num` and `total_width`) so I can use those and use `SELECT INTO` but I've seen examples with a single variable / `SELECT` statement only. What if I have more of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list [multiple variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) in the `into` part. And the [`declare` section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) needs to come before the first `begin`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f() RETURNS trigger 
AS $$
declare
  total_num bigint;
  total_width bigint;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(width)
       into total_num, total_width
   FROM some_table 
   WHERE foo = NEW.foo;

   IF total_num > 0 AND total_width > 100 THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'this is bad';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm not sure whether the emphasis here is on the use of variables or the actual `IF`. This is meant as an answer on the latter:

---

You can do this without variables using `HAVING` and `EXISTS`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ''
                  FROM some_table
                  WHERE foo = new.foo
                  HAVING count(*) > 0
                         AND sum(width) > 100) THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'this is bad';
END IF;
```

Comment: The emphasis in my case is actually on the `IF`. So, thanks, I really like this approach, it's even simpler. I still accept the other one though as that's the answer for the question.